# Having issue with mapping in spring dispatcher servlet

Tags: spring

I have a JSP page that contains a form and on submitting that form I need to call `GET` method. But with my current mapping, when I try to load my JSP page then instead of loading the JSP page it calls `GET` method.

Following are the mappings that I made.

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/test/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

TestHarnessController :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/testHarness")
public class TestHarnessController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String handleGetRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        return null;

    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String handlePostRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        return null;

    }



}
```

And my JSP page url is:
http://localhost.ms.com:8080/DataBox/test/testHarness.jsp

Please give me some suggestions as I am struggling with this since 2 -3 days.

Comment: How about change the return value of methods to void. And how did you config the viewResolver?

Comment: So what you're saying is... The form call the GET handler on submit and it does? Do you mean POST maybe?

Comment: @OQJF I am adding view resolver as                               <bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="viewClass"  value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
<property name="prefix">
<value>/test/</value>
</property>
<property name="suffix">
<value>.jsp</value>
</property>
</bean>

Comment: @BArt I have missed viewresolver so after adding that my jsp page is getting called but GET method is not getting called

Comment: Jul 22 14:03:12.905 [http-8080-Processor24] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/DataBox/test/testHarness.html] Jul 22 14:03:12.905 [http-8080-Processor24] WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/DataBox/test/testHarness.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

Comment: change <url-pattern>/test/*</url-pattern> to <url-pattern>DataBox/test/*</url-pattern>, and remove all the suffix such as jsp,html etc, and why the url is test/testHarness.html?

Comment: I have modified below things:  <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>          @Controller
public class TestHarnessController {
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/testHarness.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String handleGetRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        return null;
        
    }
    
        }     Still handleGetReq is not getting called

Comment: does anyone ahs any idea???

Comment: Can you put the JSP code as well?